# How is it called in English a group of gipsy families?

Tags: word-request

There is a wonderful movie called [“Şatra”](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073781/), original title: "Tabor ukhodit v nebo".

In my language the word ”şatră”, pronounced (ʃatrə) defines a group of gipsy families and is attributed only to gipsies.

I know that in English I can use the word clan or pride to define a group of interrelated families but I wonder if there is a specific word attributed only to gipsies like in my language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you are searching for good sir is the word [**Romani**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_people)

In terms of the application of the word to describe a family or group you could correctly use the designation **"Romani people/family/group"** as it distinctly refers to the "Gypsy" people that inhabit a wide variety of countries.

As per my knowledge and research there is no word that is similar to "şatră" specifically describing a family unit in the gypsy culture.

This is the most i can do for you, I [looked up](http://www2.arnes.si/~eusmith/Romany/glossary.html) the Romany language and I'll list out the words Romani/Gypsy and family for your convenience.

> - **Familia** - Family (Commonly used by French-Romanian Romani)
> - **Romani** - Gypsy/Romany

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks :) 
Had a lot of fun researching and learning a bit about the Gypsy culture. Did you know they are actually of Indian origin at some point? I was just amazed.

Comment: Yes, I knew it. Actually the languages are related too.

Comment: To some extent. I'm Indian too and I was dumbfounded for a minute or two. Just learning more interesting stuff everyday.

Comment: I'd like to add for those who don't know that the term *Gypsy*, although quite common, is generally considered a derogatory ethnic slur.

Comment: The shortened version, **Roma**, is often used. Also, they can be formally described as **communities**. ie. "The local Roma community"